# How to loop table rows and get header - value pair on MySQL

Tags: mysql

For example I got table like this:

```
ID | GroupID | Fee | Discount
-----------------------------
1  |   20    | 60  | 15
2  |   21    | 55  | 42
```

I want to loop each row and get header - value pair like this:
From row 1: GroupID - 20, Fee - 60, Discount - 15
From row 2: GroupID - 21, Fee - 55, Discount - 42

So basically, this is my old table and I want to convert it to the new one. The new one will look like this:

```
ID | GroupID |   Type   | Value
-------------------------------
1  |   20    |   Fee    |  60
2  |   20    | Discount |  15
3  |   21    |   Fee    |  55
4  |   21    | Discount |  42
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
t.ID,
t.GroupID,
a.Type,
IF(a.Type = 'Fee', Fee, Discount) AS `Value`
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Fee' AS Type UNION SELECT 'Discount') a
ORDER BY ID, GroupID;
```

- see it working live [here](https://rextester.com/CMN45375)

Comment: Actually total column types that I need to migrate more than those two (Fee, Discount), but thank you for the answer, I can use it :)